# compress a bitmap and save it to a bitmap object

Tags: android, bitmap

I am a beginner in android. I decoded a `Base64` image to `Bitmap` and i need to compress it to to an `Outputstream`, now i need to use the `Bitmap` get added to the `ArrayList`.

```
try {
                // Getting JSON Array from URL
             details = json.getJSONArray(TAG_Root);
                for(int i = 0; i < details.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = details.getJSONObject(i);

                 //Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String branch = c.getString(TAG_Branch);
                String address = c.getString(TAG_Add);
                String uname = c.getString(TAG_User);
                String photo = c.getString(TAG_Photo);
                System.out.println(photo);

                //decoding and compressing bitmap 
                byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(photo, Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);

                //bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open("1024x768.jpg"));
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                //Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));



                 al_branch.add(branch);
                al_add.add(address);
                al_user.add(uname);
                al_photo.add(bitmap);



                }
             System.out.println(al_branch);
              System.out.println(al_photo);  

              custom_list adapter = new custom_list(MainActivity.this, al_branch,al_user,al_add ,al_photo);
```

Comment: And what is exactly the problem? Please explain better what's not working or what are you not able to do.

Comment: Do you want to save the bitmap as a file on your phone or do you want to send it to your server?

Comment: Thanks Sebastian..I have to compress the bitmap, scale it and add it to an array arraylist...but have no idea on how to deal with it